# Dealing with unique_ptr in containers

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a vector of unique_ptrs which point to Models, Meshes, etc like this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Model>> mLoadedModels;
```

I choose unique_ptr because it automatically frees the data upon vector destructor, and also because later on if I need to for example reload all the models (due to OpenGL context tear down/created) I can just internally in my resource manager reset() and make it point to a new Model instance and it wouldnt affect the rest of the system.

My question though is, how would you share the contents of the vector with other systems? You cant just pass the unique_ptr around, because that would change the ownership (due to its unique_ptr), and I want sole ownership in the rersource manager.

The solution I came up with is the following, to wrap the access in the following struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct Handle
{
    Handle(std::unique_ptr<T>& resource) : mResource(resource)
    {
    }

    T& operator*()                  { return mResource.get(); }
    const T& operator*() const      { return mResource.get(); }
    T* operator->()                 { return mResource.get(); }
    const T* operator->() const     { return mResource.get(); }


private:
    std::unique_ptr<T>& mResource;
};

typedef Handle<Model> ModelPtr;

ModelPtr GetModel(const std::string& modelName);

// example:
ModelPtr monkey = GetModel("Monkey");
monkey->dance();

// reload resources, and then monkey dereferences to the new Model instance
```

It feels abit gimmicky though, surely theres a better, more straightforward solution to this?

Comment: Use `shared_ptr` if you need shared ownership. You could then hand out `weak_ptr`s to observers.

Comment: `Handle` should obviously be named `unique_ptr_ptr`. Kidding aside, your `Handle` will be invalidated when the vector resizes.

Comment: What's wrong with handing out raw `Model*`?

Comment: @Casey really, it should be `shared_unique_ptr` to deal with lifetime issues (I kid).

Comment: @Yakk I like to use `shared_unique_ptr*` to cover all my bases.

Comment: @Casey but what if you want to reseat it?  `shared_unique_ptr*&` to be safe.

Comment: @Yakk But you can't pass that to `std::bind`. `reference_wrapper<shared_unique_ptr*>` is far more flexible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a simple solution to this.

Pass around `vec[n].get()` -- raw pointers.  So long as you don't *store* them, and always get them back from the owner, and the owner doesn't destroy them while you are using them, you are safe.

If you aren't willing to follow that level of discipline, what you need is a `std::shared_ptr` in the `vector`, and pass around and store `std::weak_ptr`s.  The `weak_ptr`s will auto-invalidate when the last `shared_ptr` goes away (and by policy, the only persistent `shared_ptr` is the one in the owning `vector`).

This has the added advantage that if you are in the middle of doing work on an element and the `vector` clears itself, you don't segfault.  You access a `weak_ptr` by `.lock()`, which returns a `shared_ptr`, during whose lifetime the raw pointer is guaranteed to be good.

The downside is that this ups the cost, the upside is that it allows for weak shared ownership and lazy notification of invalidation.

Comment: I do need to store them though, for example my Model stores a MeshPtr and a MaterialPtr, etc. I want to make it as transparent as a pointer also, with weak_ptr you have to do lock() every time you want to access the resource right?

Comment: What about passing around a vec& and then an index number, wrapped in a struct like the Handle``

Comment: @KaiserJohaan First, There is rarely a good reason to store references in persistent objects.  Second, "transparent as a pointer" is no good if the pointer can be made invalid at any point.  `.lock()` defines a scope in which the pointer cannot be made invalid and can be safely used.  It might be overkill if you can prove that the pointer in question will only be destroyed at certain points...

Comment: Is there no good alternatives to avoid having to perform .lock() every time you access it then?

Comment: @kaiserjohaan sure: have sensible lifetime and access rules.  Who owns it provides it, and destruction happens at known times that does not overlap with non owning pointer lifetimes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a plain `std::vector <Model>` and hand out raw pointers to the individual elements. You shouldn’t need to make it any more complicated than that unless you need dynamic polymorphism or expect references to the Models to outlive the vector.

Comment: The pointers to `Model` are then invalidated if `std::vector` resizes, so they cannot persist over any code that could modify the length of the `std::vector`.

Comment: @Yakk Ah yes, that’s all too easy to forget. Now, depending on how the container is manipulated, `std::deque <Model>` might be appropriate, but probably the `std::unique_ptr`/`get` solution is the best.